# Android File dont create

Tags: android

I want to create a text file containing a string.

```
String string = "hello!";

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.txt");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I have the appropriate permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.latorre"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />...
```

But the file is not created. Why?

Comment: BTW: targetting API 10? Really?

Comment: You should check the state of the external storage before writing to it. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage) is a good introduction.

Comment: Your code works for me. What is the Android version of the device or emulator that you are using? Are you sure that the file is not being created? Are you looking for it in the correct place? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void writefile(String word1)
        try {
                    String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/";

        File logFile = new File(path + "test.txt");
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        }

        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(logFile, true);
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(fw);


            buf.append(word1);
            buf.newLine();
            buf.flush();

        }
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "hello!";

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/", "test.txt");
if (!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile();
}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: Can you please provide some context/explanation for that code? While this may solve the problem, the OP asked *why* the file is not created. Please explain what the problem is, and how your code resolves it.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but I think that when you create a file using the constructor File(path, name), the file is not actually created on storage, but just in memory. The method createNewFile() actually create the file on storage.